# Nginx permission denied 13 with Django on static content

Tags: python, django, nginx

I used this [tutorial](https://uwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html) to setup a virtualenv and the nginx server.
I did exactly what was told, but I still get a

> Permission denied (13)

error when trying to access static content.
I already set my static dir and the whole Django project to be owned by `www-data`.

Further on, if I ignore the static content and try to let everything run with emperor I run into more permission denied errors. Now for everytime I try to access the site.

```
root      8704  0.0  0.0  62780  1260 ?        Ss   16:19   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
www-data  8705  0.0  0.0  63108  1680 ?        S    16:19   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  8706  0.0  0.0  63108  1680 ?        S    16:19   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  8707  0.0  0.0  63108  1680 ?        S    16:19   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  8708  0.0  0.0  63448  2276 ?        S    16:19   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

When starting uwsgi: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f19997fd07c0237a7435 as root
When starting uwsgi with www-data:

```
root@vmd2719:~/energy1/energydrinks# uwsgi --ini django.ini --uid www-data --gid www-data
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from django.ini
open("./python27_plugin.so"): No such file or directory [core/utils.c line 3321]
!!! UNABLE to load uWSGI plugin: ./python27_plugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory !!!
*** Starting uWSGI 1.9.6 (64bit) on [Mon Apr 15 16:24:49 2013] ***
compiled with version: 4.6.3 on 15 April 2013 11:52:36
os: Linux-3.2.0-40-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 25 21:22:10 UTC 2013
nodename: vmd2719
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /root/energy1/energydrinks
writing pidfile to /tmp/energy-master.pid
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
setgid() to 33
setuid() to 33
chdir(): Permission denied [core/uwsgi.c line 2063]
chdir(): Permission denied [core/uwsgi.c line 1249]
chdir(): Permission denied [core/uwsgi.c line 1269]
```

Nginx debug log on accessing a static file:

```
2013/04/15 16:20:25 [debug] 8708#0: *1 http filename: "/root/energy1/energydrinks/static/jgrowl/jquery.jgrowl.js"
2013/04/15 16:20:25 [debug] 8708#0: *1 add cleanup: 0000000001F68C10
2013/04/15 16:20:25 [error] 8708#0: *1 open() "/root/energy1/energydrinks/static/jgrowl/jquery.jgrowl.js" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 109.193.75.142, server: .de, request: "GET /static/jgrowl/jquery.jgrowl.js HTTP/1.1", host: ".de:8000", referrer: "http://.de:8000/member/register/"
2013/04/15 16:20:25 [debug] 8708#0: *1 http finalize request: 403, "/static/jgrowl/jquery.jgrowl.js?" a:1, c:1
2013/04/15 16:20:25 [debug] 8708#0: *1 http special response: 403, "/static/jgrowl/jquery.jgrowl.js?"
2013/04/15 16:20:25 [debug] 8708#0: *1 http set discard body
2013/04/15 16:20:25 [debug] 8708#0: *1 xslt filter header
2013/04/15 16:20:25 [debug] 8708#0: *1 charset: "" > "utf-8"
2013/04/15 16:20:25 [debug] 8708#0: *1 HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

Comment: Have you checked your permissions with `ls -l`?

Comment: @thegrinner yep, because I was enraged I nearly set everything you could imagine to chown -R www-data:www-data.

Comment: Check your Nginx error logs - they may shed some light on the problem.

Comment: @krak3n already did that. It says permission denied 13. The error nor the access log gave me anything of use. And nothing of the already posted fixes can help me. I do the setup as root user, installing virtualenv etc. should I create a fresh user?

Comment: Please check that nginx is effectively running as user www-data. Also, are you running your tests on actual static files or on the directory itself ? Also, please post your nginx configuration.

Comment: Check the permissions of the collected static assets directory is ``755``: ``chmod -R 755 /path/to/static``

Comment: http://catherinetenajeros.blogspot.com/2013/04/server-error-nginx-and-uwsgi.html

Comment: `chmod +x /path/to/static` (and other directories that need to be readable by nginx)

Comment: surprised this was ruled off-topic? @will, u cld at least move it to eg serverfault if you thought it was too server-ey. i'd be interested in more answers.

Comment: @hwjp feel free to do so

Comment: @hwjp can't.  It might be too old for any mod to migrate it :/  You can flag and ask if it really matters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So your nginx is running as `www-data` inside `/root`... That can't be good. `/root` is not accessible by normal users (unless you `chmod +x` it, which is a bad idea).

You should move your data outside of it, in `/srv/http`, `/var/www` or `/home/whatever`, but not in `/root`.

Comment: Just realized that. :)

Comment: Then where can i put the static files?

Comment: @Raja As stated in my answer: `/srv/http`, `/var/www`, `/home/whatever`... Anything you like, really, as long as it's readable by the nginx user.

Answer (score 2):

If your nginx is not in production, can you add "error_log /path/to/log debug;" then try to access one of your static content. You'll see what nginx is trying to load in the debug file. It should be useful.

Don't hesitate to post its content here to help us understand.